# Display screen flash like the iOS camera app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I would like to implement something like is done in the native iOS camera app - when I user takes a picture the screen flashes dark for a split second.

I am using a UIImagePicker with an overlay, and want to add a second view on top.

Here is some code:

TOP:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,
                  UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
var cameraUI:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
var overlay:UIImageView!
```

PRESENTING THE CAMERA:

```
func presentCamera()
{
    cameraUI = UIImagePickerController()
    cameraUI.delegate = self
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = false
    cameraUI.showsCameraControls = false

    var translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 71.0); //This slots the preview exactly in the middle of the screen by moving it down 71 points
    cameraUI.cameraViewTransform = translate;

    var scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 1.333333, 1.333333);
    cameraUI.cameraViewTransform = scale;


    self.presentViewController(cameraUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
    overlay = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
    var image = UIImage(named: "bg.png")
    overlay.image = image
    overlay.userInteractionEnabled = true
    overlay.alpha = 1.0
    cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = overlay

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("tapped:"))
    recognizer.delegate = self
    recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    overlay.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

}
```

Flash Screen: called when user takes a picture

```
func flashScreen() {
    let flashView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
    flashView.alpha = 0.0
    flashView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    print("flash")

    overlay.addSubview(flashView)
//        self.view.addSubview(flashView) doesn't work either
```

I don't see anything

I also tried changing the overlay image which did not seem to work either:

```
//        overlay.alpha = 0.0
//        overlay.image = UIImage(named: "flash.png")
//        cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = overlay
```

Comment: I noticed `flashView.alpha = 0.0`, which means it's transparent.  Shouldn't this be 1.0?

Comment: Oh boy, that might be it hah. I'll try that when I get home. Thanks :)

Comment: @rFessler. That worked! Thanks a lot. If you write it as an answer I will submit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed flashView.alpha = 0.0, which means it's transparent. Set it to 1.0.